# If $f ' (x ; y)=0$ for every $x$ in open convex set, then $f$ is constant on open convex set.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

$f′(x;y)=0$ for every $x$ in an open convex set $S$ and every $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$,

Prove that $f$ is constant on $S$.

$f′(x;y)$ is the derivative at $x$ in the direction $y$.

Seems like I have to use Mean Value theorem.

And , I should say that this question is seemingly trivial, but can't think of how to start

Answer (score 1):

If $f'(x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)$ as you wrote, then $f$ does not need to be constant.

Take for example $f:\mathbb R \times \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R: (x,y) \mapsto x$. It is $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y) = 0$ for each $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$, but $f$ is not constant...